# How to call printf in machine language

Tags: c, assembly

Let's say we have the assembly code that prints Z to the screen.

```
pushl $'Z'
call putchar
add $4, %esp
```

How can we write this in machine language code?  I've checked both online resources and this code in gdb, but the former disagrees with the latter and the latter changes each time I run the code.  Thank you for your help.

I'm using linux x86.  Again, I'd like to say that I want to know how to write this in machine language code.

Comment: Why are you using assembly language?

Comment: Machine language (i. e. hex code) or assembly?

Answer (score 3):

Use `putchar` instead of `printf` . `printf` needs a `string`, and you have provided it a `char`. Also, remember that you have to restore the stack just after calling your function, as both `printf` and `putchar` uses the `cdecl` calling convention.

```
pushl $'Z'
call putchar
add $4, %esp
```

Comment: Worth noting that if the machine is amd64, the abi requires the first argument to be in %rdi, not on the stack, assuming you're using the SysV ABI. Other calling conventions for x86 architectures at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions.